# Integrate Mule-esb with Spring 4

Tags: mule, esb, spring-4

I have an application using Mule ESB with spring 3.
Now I want to upgrade to Spring 4, but it seem to be the Mule esb does not support spring 4.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Spring 3 is supported  by Mule until version 3.6.x. Mule 3.7 will support Spring 4.

Take into account that from spring 3 to 4 as a major release deprecated code is deleted.